# Android - Native crash at /system/lib/libhwui.so

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, galaxy-tab, .so

I got this **error**: Native crash at /system/lib/libhwui.so in the Google play and it's happen only in `android 4.4`and only in Galaxy Tab E 9.6 (gtelwifi), below is the full error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I find similar answers in this site but nothing was help me.